# I want the result of division in two digits in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am taking the input as a date i.e, dd/mm/yyyy. I want the output as yyww.d
, where yy is year, ww is week number and d is day number of week.
This is my code.

```
st1 = drDataTask[0]["text_value"].ToString();
if (Math.Max(st1.IndexOf('M'), 0) != 0)
{
    dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(st1.Substring(0, Math.Max(st1.IndexOf('M') + 1, 0))).ToString("yy");
    dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(st1.Substring(0, Math.Max(st1.IndexOf('M') + 1, 0))).DayOfYear / 7;
    dt3 = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToDateTime(st1.Substring(0, Math.Max(st1.IndexOf('M') + 1, 0))).DayOfWeek);
    rowPublishData[27] = dt1 + dt2 + "." + dt3;
 }
```

if week number is 6, year is 2018 and day is tuesday, output should be 1806.2
I am getting the output as 186.2
How can I get the output as yyww.d instead of yyw.d?

Comment: so what is problem. You code does not work or some error ?

Comment: for dt2 variable I want the result in 2 digits. If the week number is greater than 9 then it is working fine. But for week number from 1-9 also, i want the result in 2 digits. Like if week number is 6, dt2 should be 06 not 6.

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(st1, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var weekOfYear = Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dt);
var dayOfWeek = (int)dt.DayOfWeek;
var dayOfWeekValue = dayOfWeek.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');

var result = dt.ToString("yy") + weekOfYear + dayOfWeak;
```

Answer (score 2):

When and where a week starts is different from country to country and from year to year. Sometimes the first few days of a new year belong to week 53 of the last year, sometimes not.

There are methods to handle this different kind of calender-settings inside the System.Globalisation namespace. The calender also will tell you which week you are in a given DateTime based on the year and rules you apply.

You can read here: [Calendar.GetWeekOfYear()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or try this:

```
using System; 
using System.Globalization; 

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var dt = DateTime.Now;

        DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
        Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;

        var yourFormat = string.Format(
            "{0:yy}{1:00}.{2:d}"
            , dt
            , cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt,CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            , dt.DayOfWeek )

        Console.WriteLine(yourFormat);
    } 
}
```

I am assuming Sunday is your day 0 as your example mentions tuesday to be day 2.

The output of your format for the 1st Jan 2000 - 2020 with this method is:

```
1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM => 0052.6 // this should probaby be 9952.6 
1/1/2001 12:00:00 AM => 0101.1
1/1/2002 12:00:00 AM => 0201.2
1/1/2003 12:00:00 AM => 0301.3
1/1/2004 12:00:00 AM => 0453.4 // this should probaby be 0353.4
1/1/2005 12:00:00 AM => 0552.6 // this should probaby be 0452.6
1/1/2006 12:00:00 AM => 0601.0
1/1/2007 12:00:00 AM => 0701.1
1/1/2008 12:00:00 AM => 0801.2
1/1/2009 12:00:00 AM => 0953.4 // this should probaby be 0853.4
1/1/2010 12:00:00 AM => 1052.5 // this should probaby be 0953.5
1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM => 1152.6 // this should probaby be 1053.6
1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM => 1201.0
1/1/2013 12:00:00 AM => 1301.2
1/1/2014 12:00:00 AM => 1401.3
1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM => 1553.4  // this should probaby be 1453.4
1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM => 1652.5  // this should probaby be 1552.5
1/1/2017 12:00:00 AM => 1701.0
1/1/2018 12:00:00 AM => 1801.1
1/1/2019 12:00:00 AM => 1901.2
```

---

To fix the output year, you need to substract 1 year if your week is >= 52:

```
var week = cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
var fixOutputYear = week >= 52 ? -1 : 0;

Console.WriteLine(
    string.Format("{3} => {0:yy}{1:00}.{2:d}"
                  , dt.AddYears(fixOutputYear)
                  , week
                  , dt.DayOfWeek
                  , dt));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a [custom number format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) on `dt2` to ensure it is always 2 digits:

```
int dt2 = 6;
dt2.ToString("00")

// output "06"
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution:

Replace

```
rowPublishData[27] = dt1 + dt2 + "." + dt3;
```

With

```
rowPublishData[27] = dt1 + dt2.ToString("00") + "." + dt3;
```